# Pi 4, Bluetooth 5, Long-Range mode

Tags: bluetooth

I'm playing about with flic buttons and the flicd service and only getting about 10m range indoors at the moment. Although Bluetooth 5 has the Coded PHY mode for long-range, I've read that the pi4 (or indeed many chips that handle both wifi and bluetooth) can't make use of this mode.
So my question is has anyone had any success with long-range bluetooth 5 on the pi 4? Separate USB dongle?
Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not with bluetooth, no. I've had much better results with zigbee, though.